# How to use /sudo:username@remotehost: in dired mode for emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, dired

When I use emacs, I input

```
M-x dired
```

then I input

```
/sudo:ukari@ubuntu-hadoop-0:
```

emacs returns

`` Host `ubuntu-hadoop-0' looks like a remote host, `sudo' can only use the local host ``

How do I  make the dired rule works as I wanted?

Answer (score 1):

TRAMP [supports multiple hops via its `tramp-default-proxies-alist` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Multi_002dhops.html#Multi_002dhops):

> If you, for example, wants to work as '`root`' on hosts in the domain '`your.domain`', but login as '`root`' is disabled for non-local access, you might add the following rule:
>
> ```
> (add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist
>          '("\\.your\\.domain\\'" "\\`root\\'" "/ssh:%h:"))
> ```
>
> Opening `/sudo:randomhost.your.domain:` would connect first '`randomhost.your.domain`' via `ssh` under your account name, and perform `sudo -u root` on that host afterwards.

Sometimes it can be a pain to manually configure this variable, so there is also an [ad-hoc multi-hop feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Ad_002dhoc-multi_002dhops.html) that lets you multi-hop on the fly. (This feature actually modifies `tramp-default-proxies-alist` for you in your current session.)

To use the ad-hoc feature, try the following string:

```
/ssh:ukari@ubuntu-hadoop-0|sudo:root@ubuntu-hadoop-0:
```

Answer (score 0):

try my `toggle-read-only-file-with-sudo`

```
(when (member system-type '(gnu/linux darwin))
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c o") 'toggle-read-only-file-with-sudo))
```

https://github.com/jixiuf/emacs_conf/blob/master/site-lisp/joseph/joseph-sudo.el

after you input `:/sudo:ukari@ubuntu-hadoop-0:`
you just need to press `"C-c o"`  it will use sudo on the remote host

usage:

`1.`when you edit a local file , and press C-c o  ,it will trying edit it using sudo

`2.`when you edit a local file with sudo(edit as root) , and press C-c o it will  edit this file as current login user

`3.` when you edit a remote file as normal user(suppose it is ukari) and you press C-c o  it will edit it as root on remote host ,press C-c o again  it will drop back to ukari again